# I am trying to import html text in CSV with beautiful soup but script outputs "blank" CSV

Tags: python-3.x, web, web-scraping

I have written below code to get the data from the website in  CSV.
Basically I am interested in text like this in entirety.

```
(Beskrivning:
PL-CH-DSPTC-AD10Semi-professional Technician / Administrator: Vocationally trained positions that need both practical and theoretical understanding and some significant advanced vocational experience to perform broad range of varying tasks and issues, in related field of work. Work performed is still procedurized, however issues and problems)
```

So My table should have one row for each description please

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv

url = "http://www.altrankarlstad.com/wisp"
page = requests.get(url)
pagetext = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(pagetext, 'html.parser')

gdp_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "table workitems-table mt-2"})

def table_to_df(table):
    return pd.DataFrame([[td.text for td in row.findAll('td')] for row in table.tbody.findAll('tr')])

file = open("data.csv", 'w')

for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    for col in row.find_all('td'):
        print(col.text)
```

Comment: Did you try `df.to_csv()`?

Comment: you created a function to parse table tag? `pd.read_html()` is the exact function you created

Comment: Hi Jack and chitown, I guess I am stuck right after return pd statement. My script doesnot write anything even with above suggestion you both made. Could you please help me how best I incorporate them...?